Why does Killua have cat ears
In some of the episodes of Hunter X Hunter it will show a flash scene of Killua Zoldyck with white cat ears. Why is that? Does it have a hidden meaning?

I guess you mean Killua like this. There's nothing really hidden, but simply it symbolizes Killua being whimsical, or stereotypical cat-like.

This technique was also used in Komi Can't communicate later on.

It's a symbolic way to give the character traits a cat has momentarily, like wanting to cuddle or being territorial.
It's just one of those "cute" tropes that you'll see over and over again in manga and anime. Another example I can think of is in The Apothecary Diaries. There is usually no hidden meaning.
Cats are very popular in anime and Japan in general with many anime faces taking on a subtle feline shape even if no cat ears or other cat features are present.
